# ImportError Django cannot import name 'SignupView'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

So I imported the 'LoginView, LogoutView' but when I tried to import the 'SignupView' I got the following error: ImportError: cannot import name 'SignupView' from 'django.contrib.auth.views' (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\djang0\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py)

This is what I believe to be the necessary code.

```
#my views.py

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.views import generic
from django.http import HttpResponse
from.models import Lead, Agent
from.forms import LeadForm, LeadModelForm

class SignupView(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = "registration/signup.html"
    form_class = UserCreationForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("login")


#my app urls.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView, SignupView
from django.urls import path, include
from leads.views import hero_page, HeroPageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', HeroPageView.as_view(), name="hero-page"),
    path('leads/', include('leads.urls', namespace="leads")),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('signup/', SignupView.as_view(), name="signup"),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I don't know what to try, I'm kind of a beginner in Django. I've done a lot of research on multiple sites and articles but only person I've seen who had a similar problem had to remove the 'views' from the 'from django.contrib.auth.views' because they ran on an older version of Django which I believe to have been 2.0.1 but I'm running on Django version %.0.1 which I hear is valid.
Any help will be highly appreciated and please explain in a way any beginner can understand.

Comment: It looks like you have written your own `SignupView` class in your `views.py` module.  Why are you trying to import it from `django.contrib.auth.views`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the `SignupView` in your own `views.py`, hence you import it from there:

```
from app_name.views import SignupView
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView  # no SignupView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', HeroPageView.as_view(), name='hero-page'),
    path('leads/', include('leads.urls', namespace='leads')),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('signup/', SignupView.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```

That being said, your view seems to only inject a different template and a different success URL, you can just plug these into the `CreateView`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView  # no SignupView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', HeroPageView.as_view(), name='hero-page'),
    path('leads/', include('leads.urls', namespace='leads')),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path(
        'signup/',
        CreateView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/signup.html',
            form_class=UserCreationForm,
            success_url=reverse_lazy('login'),
        ),
        name='signup',
    ),
]
```

Comment: ` from website.models import SignupView
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView ` After making the suggested change in my urls I get the following error  ModuleNotFoundError message: No module named 'website.models... Any other suggestions? If I use `leaads.models import SignupView` I get the old error. @willeM_ Van Onsem

Comment: `website.models`? Shouldn't this be `website.views`?